# How to put traits in Rust's function types in an array's type?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to create an array of functions that sort numbers, but am having issues with the declaring the array's type. I can't get it to be generic over the input parameter of the functions.

How do I accomplish that the array `sorts` has functions whose first and only parameter only require implementing the traits `Ord` and `Copy` instead of being `u32`?

```rust
// What I have now. Note the fn(&mut [u32])
let sorts: [(&'static str, fn(&mut [u32])); 6] = [
    ("Insertion sort", insertion_sort),
    ("Selection sort", selection_sort),
    ("Bubble sort", bubble_sort),
    ("Merge sort", merge_sort),
    ("Quick sort", quick_sort),
    ("Heap sort", heap_sort),
];

fn insertion_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }
fn selection_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }
fn bubble_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }
fn merge_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }
fn quick_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }
fn heap_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }

// What I want to accomplish. Note the fn(&mut [impl Ord + Copy])
let sorts: [(&'static str, fn(&mut [impl Ord + Copy])); 6] = [
    ("Insertion sort", insertion_sort),
    ("Selection sort", selection_sort),
    ("Bubble sort", bubble_sort),
    ("Merge sort", merge_sort),
    ("Quick sort", quick_sort),
    ("Heap sort", heap_sort),
];
```

The reason I would like to do this is so that I don't need to change the type of the sorting functions array when apply them to an array of numbers of a different type.

**EDIT:** What I want to accomplish is the following. Basically I want to test different sorting implementations easily by applying them in turn to an array defined earlier. The `sorts` array is used as follows, including the answer as provided by syskov.

```
fn main() {
    let problem: [u8; 32] = rand::random();
    fn create_sorts<T: Ord + Copy>() -> [(&'static str, fn(&mut [T])); 7] {
        [
            ("Insertion sort", insertion_sort),
            ("Selection sort", selection_sort),
            ("Bubble sort", bubble_sort),
            ("Merge sort", merge_sort),
            ("Quick sort", quick_sort),
            ("Heap sort", heap_sort),
            ("Stooge sort", stooge_sort),
        ]
    }

    println!("{:?}", problem);
    for (name, sort) in create_sorts().iter() {
        let mut problem_ = problem.clone();

        let now = Instant::now();
        sort(&mut problem_);
        let elapsed = now.elapsed();

        let judgment: &str = match is_sorted(&problem_) {
            true => "✓",
            false => "✗",
        };

        println!("{} in {:?}: {}", judgment, elapsed, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Simply :** In your current code; what you are doing is called as `static dispatch`, at the end you must define the concrete type that you need. What you are expecting is called `dynamic dispatch`, here is the [solution with dynamic dispatch](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ee7c119fe6d222f11b0fe838d73fddc).

Comment: But you need to know that `dynamic dispatch` brings performance cost (_imo: in this case it shouldn't be used_), please [read this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#trait-objects-perform-dynamic-dispatch), see also [brief for static dispatch vs dynamic dispatch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-beta/book/static-and-dynamic-dispatch.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly context when **sorts** is used, but you can have some sort of generic function it based on numbers array you sort. It would reduce boilerplate.

```
fn main () {
    fn insertion_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }
    fn selection_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }
    fn bubble_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }
    fn merge_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }
    fn quick_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }
    fn heap_sort(array: &mut [impl Ord + Copy]) { }

    fn create_sorts<T: Ord + Copy>() -> [(&'static str, fn (&mut [T])); 6] {
        [
            ("Insertion sort", insertion_sort),
            ("Selection sort", selection_sort),
            ("Bubble sort", bubble_sort),
            ("Merge sort", merge_sort),
            ("Quick sort", quick_sort),
            ("Heap sort", heap_sort),
        ]
    }

    let sorts_u32 = create_sorts::<u32>();
    let sorts_u64 = create_sorts::<u64>();
}
```

Comment: I added a comment explaining what I want to do with `sorts`. I'm not sure your approach is the solution I need, because if `problem`'s type changes (`[u32]` -> `[i8]`) I need to manually call `create_sorts::<i8>` instead of `create_sorts::<u32>` right?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to make `sorts`' input parameter type dependent on the `problem` array's type so that I don't need to manually update the first if the second changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a generic function or struct to store your array. Something similar to examples below.

```
fn dumb<T>() 
where T : Ord + Copy
{

    // What I want to accomplish. Note the fn(&mut [impl Ord + Copy])
    let sorts: [(&'static str, fn(&mut [T])); 6] = [
        ("Insertion sort", insertion_sort),
        ("Selection sort", selection_sort),
        ("Bubble sort", bubble_sort),
        ("Merge sort", merge_sort),
        ("Quick sort", quick_sort),
        ("Heap sort", heap_sort),
    ];

}
```

---

```
struct Sorts<T> 
where T : Ord + Copy
{
    sorts : [(&'static str, fn(&mut [T])); 6]
}

impl<T> Sorts<T> 
where T : Ord + Copy
{

    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Sorts {
            sorts : [
                ("Insertion sort", insertion_sort),
                ("Selection sort", selection_sort),
                ("Bubble sort", bubble_sort),
                ("Merge sort", merge_sort),
                ("Quick sort", quick_sort),
                ("Heap sort", heap_sort),
            ]
        }
    }

}
```